# When to use amplify_video parameter when uploading media to twitter?

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to upload videos to Twitter using API. It is not clear when to use the **amplify_video** parameter. This [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/uploading-media) says that the *use of the amplify_video media category is required if uploading a video > 140 seconds in length or if being used in an Twitter Ads campaign. Whitelisting is needed at the @handle level to upload long videos.*

I have some questions regarding this

- How do we get whitelisted?
- How to check the status of whitelisting for long video upload using api?
- What happens when we use amplify_video parameter without whitelisting?(for both videos < 140 sec and videos greater than 140 sec). Is there a situation where amplify_video parameter fails and tweet_video works!